# Monthly Asset Depreciation

Tags: java, netbeans

I am writing a desktop application which will be used to calculate the monthly depreciation and Accumulation of an asset.

The accumulation is based on the number of months the user specifies.
therefore if the user specified 12 months, it should accumulate over those months.

Also the user should be able to view the accumulation value for for every month so far it is in the specified number of months. e.g if i select January it should give me the accumulated value for January and so on......

### CHALLENGES : first challenge is getting the accumulation values for all the user specified months 2nd one is how to link this concept with my j form and my database since the codes i have works but how to fuse it into my program is a problem.

### Depreciation Method: Straight line

below is a sample code

```
 private void getAccumulation() {

     try {

         for (int row = 0; row <= 5; row++) {

             double Cost_Of_Acquisition = 2000;
             double Estimated_Residual_Value = 250;
             int Estimated_Useful_Life = 5;

             int depreciationMethod = 1;


             System.out.println(" acquisition cost of asset = " + (int) Cost_Of_Acquisition);
             System.out.println(" salvage value = " + (int) Estimated_Residual_Value);
             System.out.println(" number of months = " + Estimated_Useful_Life);
             System.out.println(" depreciation method  = " + depreciationMethod);

             for (int y = 1; y <= 5; y++) {
                 switch (depreciationMethod) {

                     case 1:
                         System.out.println(" straight line depreciation ");
                         double StraightLineDepreciation = ((Cost_Of_Acquisition - Estimated_Residual_Value) / Estimated_Useful_Life);
                         double AccumulatedDeprecaitionSL = (StraightLineDepreciation * y);
                         System.out.println("Asset number " + "1" + " uses straight line depreciation");
                         System.out.println(" depreciation charge for asset number " + "1" + " in month " + y + "=" + StraightLineDepreciation);
                         System.out.println("accumulated depreciation is " + AccumulatedDeprecaitionSL);
                         break;
                     case 2:
                         System.out.println(" sum of months digits depreciation ");
                         int SumofMonths = (0);
                         break;

                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: You should take accounting class!

Comment: Please be more specific about your question. Please indent your code properly and use the standard conventions for capitalization so the code is readable.

Comment: this code works!! but i want the values to be inserted manually by the user by using text fields. that is one problem

Comment: with this the values are already declared but i want the values to be inputted when the program is running.So when u enter the cost,life ,residual value and click on a calculate button, it does the depreciation and accumulation and output the results.